# I'm struggling to understand how to use the Flet UI library together the python-osc

Tags: python, osc, flet

I understand how to use pythonosc to receive OSC messages and I was able to use the Flet library to mock up a UI. What I cannot figure out is how to update the UI when I receive a new OSC message.

Here is my code. It correctly listens for incoming OSC messages and prints them to the console, but I cannot figure out how to make it update the UI.

```
import datetime
import time
import socket

import flet as ft

from pythonosc.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from pythonosc import osc_server

def main(page: ft.Page):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    show_event = "The event has not yet been set"
    show_venue = "The venue not yet set been set"
    show_scene = "n/a"
    show_next = "n/a"
    # show_message = "None"

    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    ip_port = 5001
    show_message = "Ready to receive OSC messages at " + ip_address + ":" + str(ip_port)


    # Start page
    page.title = "Show - timmrogers@gmail.com"
    # page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
    # page.window_full_screen = True,
    page.window_width = "1280"
    page.window_height = "720"
    # page.window_min_width = "1280"
    # page.window_min_height = "720"
    page.window_left = 0
    page.window_top = 0
    page.window_bgcolor = ft.colors.BLACK
    page.bgcolor = ft.colors.BLACK

    page.update() 

    page.add(

        # Start row
        ft.Row(
            [
                # Event
                ft.Card(
                    color=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    # elevation=10,
                    # shadow_color=ft.colors.BLACK,

                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.EVENT, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Event"),
                                # subtitle=ft.Text("Prelude to a Kiss"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text(show_event),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=500,
                    padding=10,
                    )
                ),
 
                # Venue
                ft.Card(
                    color=ft.colors.BLUE,

                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.HOME, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Venue"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text(show_venue),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=500,
                    padding=10,
                    ),
                ), 

            ],

            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
        ),
        # End row

        # Start row
        ft.Row(
            [
                # Preshow
                ft.Card(
                     color=ft.colors.GREY,        

                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.SCHEDULE, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Preshow"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text(current_time),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=250,
                    padding=10,
                    )
                ),
                # Top
                ft.Card(
                     color=ft.colors.GREY,        
 
                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.SCHEDULE, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Top"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text("00:00:00"),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=250,
                    padding=10,
                    )
                ),
                # Intermission
                ft.Card(
                    color=ft.colors.GREY,        

                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.SCHEDULE, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Intermission"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text("00:00:00"),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=250,
                    padding=10,
                    )
                ),
                # Curtain
                ft.Card(
                    color=ft.colors.GREY,        

                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.SCHEDULE, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Curtain"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text("00:00:00"),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=250,
                    padding=10,
                    )
                ),

            ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
        ),
        # End row

        # Start row
        ft.Row(
            [
                # Scene
                ft.Card(
                    color=ft.colors.GREEN,
                    # elevation=5.0,

                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.THEATER_COMEDY, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Scene"),
                                # subtitle=ft.Text("Act 1, Scene 3"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text(show_scene),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=300,
                    padding=10,
                    )
                ),
 
                # Next
                ft.Card(
                    color=ft.colors.YELLOW,

                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.NEXT_PLAN, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Next"),
                                # subtitle=ft.Text("2.1"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text(show_next),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=300,
                    padding=10,
                    ),
                ),
 
            ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
        ),
        # End row

       # Start row
        ft.Row(
            [
                # Message
                ft.Card(
                    color=ft.colors.RED,
                    # elevation=5.0,

                    content=ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Column(
                        [
                            ft.ListTile(
                                leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.INFO, color=ft.colors.WHITE, size=64),
                                title=ft.Text("Message"),
                                subtitle=ft.Text(show_message),
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    # bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER,
                    width=800,
                    padding=10,
                    )
                ),
            ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
        ),
        # End row

    # End page
    )

    def handle_message(address, *args):

        # check for commands
        if address == "/event":
            show_event = args[0]
            print(show_event)
        elif address == "/venue":
            show_venue = args[0]
            print(show_venue)
        elif address == "/scene":
            show_scene = args[0]
            print(show_scene)
        elif address == "/next":
            show_next = args[0]
            print(show_next)

        page.update()
   
    def default_handler(address, *args):
        # print(f"DEFAULT {address}: {args}")
        show_message = address
        print(show_message)
        page.update()


    # Create the OSC server
    dispatcher = Dispatcher()
    # dispatcher.map("/message", handle_message)
    dispatcher.map("/event", handle_message)
    dispatcher.map("/venue", handle_message)
    dispatcher.map("/scene", handle_message)
    dispatcher.map("/next", handle_message)
    # dispatcher.map("/exit", exit_handler)
    dispatcher.set_default_handler(default_handler)
    server = osc_server.ThreadingOSCUDPServer((ip_address,ip_port), dispatcher)
    server.serve_forever()

# Start GUI
ft.app(target=main)
```

I am just not comfortable enough with this sort of programming to see what I am missing. Any help or suggestions would be super welcome!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).